# How include binary library in gradle native project?

Tags: c++, gradle

What I have to add in my `gradle.build` file, if I want add some binary library such as:

```
.
├── include
│   └── another.hh
├── lib
│   └── libanother.so
└── share
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a few lines in your gradle.build file to define cpp support and a few flags along with the the platforms supported.

```
 externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
        }
    }
    ndk { // these platforms cover 99% percent of all Android devices
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16', '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE', '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static', "-DPATH_TO_YOURSDKNAME:STRING=${your_sdk_path}"
            cFlags '-O3', '-fsigned-char' // full optimization, char data type is signed
            cppFlags '-fsigned-char', "-I${your_sdk_path}"
        }
    }
```

You also need to define path to your CMake file(responsible for building) like

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

I would suggest you going through [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code) especially the configure CMake and link gradle section.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for answer. This code used android plugin, but I want use gradle for my cpp project on desktop GNU/Linux. Will it work?

Comment: The code I have given you is for android native application in which a C++ SDK is being used. Can you please let me know what your application target environment is and what components you have that need to be linked?

Comment: I conduct Monte-Carlo simulation used special framework which building with cmake. Usually, in my project I also use cmake, but gradle is more powerful build tool ( I use gradle in my Kotlin project), and I want use its for my cpp project, but I don't understand how link external cmake build in my gradle project. My target: `targetMachines.add(machines.linux.x86_64)`